# JSON stringify re-structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, stringify

I have a database, with multiple cells, and under each cell, values.

Cells are: id, name, duration, date, and relationid

I have this code:

```js
var result = {} 
properties.data.forEach(addToResult); //Get data from database using properties.data
    
instance.data.datavarb = JSON.stringify(result); //Send data after converted to JSON
      
function addToResult(pair,isjson){ //operations
if(isjson===true) result[pair.key] = JSON.parse(pair.value); else result[pair.key] = pair.value;
}
```

I'm facing 2 problems:

**1- First problem:**
This is how i get the value after converted to JSON:

```
{"id":"1","name":"Football","duration":"12","date":"02-07-2018","relationid":null}
```

**How i need to be:**

```
{id:1, name:"Football", duration:12, date:"02-07-2018", relationid:null}
```

Need remove the **""** quotes from the numbers (id, duration and relationid) and the id,duration,relationid values.

**2- Second problem:**
In the problem 1, just for show you I only was parsing one of the three values from my database. What happens when I parse them all? This is how it looks like:

```
{"id":"1, 2, 3","name":"Football, France, Belgium","duration":"12, 4, 3","date":"02-07-2018, 08-07-2018, 10-07-2018","relationid":", 1, 1"}
```

Instead of creating one by one, it creates the same identifiers (id,name,duration) and put all the values in the same. For my prupose i need to be:

```
{id:1, name:"Football", duration:12, date:"02-07-2018", relationid:null},
{id:2, name:"France", duration:4, date:"08-07-2018", relationid:1},
{id:3, name:"Belgium", duration:3, date:"10-07-2018", relationid:1}
```

Many thanks!!

Comment: JSON **insists** that property names be quoted; it's not JSON if they're not.

Comment: JSON isn't converting the values to strings, they must have been strings in the original `properties.data`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Pointy but i'm trying to use this resource: https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__loading.html Check how their loading data works.

Comment: @K3ny1 If you look at their `tasks.json` example, it has quotes around the property names.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar Do you think is there any way via javascript code to convert that strings as I want? Because there's no chance to changing them from properties.data

Comment: `result[pair.key] = parseInt(result[pair.value])` when the key is `id` or `duration`.

Comment: @Barmar hmm nice point, i will try right now loading it directly using that (but) im more confortable with the second example, which i have control of everyhing.

Comment: keys of a JSON are always strings, even if you don't put double quotes on them. So what's the problem?

Comment: You mean "Loading from Object"? In Javascript object literals, there's no difference between quoting and not quoting the property names.

Comment: Well, when i try to run the Gantt using this value: {"id":"1","name":"Football","duration":"12","date":"02-07-2018","relationid":null} i get error on console, and doesn't loads properly.

Comment: What is the error which you receive? And what tool are you referring to when you mentioned "Gantt"

Comment: When i mention gantt i refer to the link that i posted.. dhtmlx gantt. The error: x3:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (datastore_hooks.js:289)
    at o._parseInner (datastore.js:24)
    at o.parse (treedatastore.js:68)
    at Object.t._process_loading (load.js:87)
    at Object.t.on_load (load.js:80)
    at Object.t.parse (load.js:33)
    at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at g.create_code (x3:100), <anonymous>:53:7)
    at j (x3:8)
    at k (x3:8)

Answer (score 2):

You can test whether the values look like integers, and parse them.

```
function addToResult(pair,isjson){ //operations
    if(isjson===true) {
        result[pair.key] = JSON.parse(pair.value); 
    } else if (/^\d+$/.test(pair.value)) {
        result[pair.key] = Number(pair.value);
    } else {
        result[pair.key] = pair.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, will test it now, btw I think in the else if is missing a )
Thanks!

Comment: Yep, I do that all the time here, too used to IDE that automatically balances....

Comment: Hello Barmar seems the code works well, but i'm facing a little problem that is my code is running before the it gets the value from the database, and is returning me a missing value error.

Comment: This code should be in the callback function of the database query.

Comment: Thanks so much @Barmar, i'm so near to do it. I need to remove also the "" from the id,name,duration,date titles. Is possible like you did?

Comment: Property names are always strings, it's not possible to remove the quotes.

Comment: When you're writing object literals in Javascript the quotes are optional, but they're still treated as strings.

Comment: In other words, there are no quotes to remove, they're just part of the way objects are printed.